# looking for a function for reading doubles in txt column by column (boost is welcome)

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm looking for a function that accepts the name of a txt file and a column number and returns the data of that column.

`std::vector<double> getColumn<std::string& file, const int& NumColumn>`

The format of the file is as follows

```
12.333  10.4  3.4
12.333  10.4  3.4
12.333  10.4  3.4
12.333  10.4  3.4
```

**Note**: I can implement this function but my question if there is a built-in function in boost or STL since this feature is beneficial. Matlab has a function to handle tabulated data called `load`

Comment: boost::spirit::qi is boost's parser. Very powerful, definitely overkill. I can hold your hand and walk through it if  you want.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @RussellGreene that's a good option. Linked to a dupe that includes comparisons too